# call python class method from c++ in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Consider a Callback class in Python.

```
class My_Callback():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def do_something(self, something):
        print(something)
```

This Class is used in a DLL wrapper which is using pybind11 to expose it to python. A reference to the Class is stored in an ENUM and passed to a C++ function.

```
void callPy(py::object f) {
    //call f.do_something("test");
}
// ...
callPy(userData::myCallback);
```

There are many examples on how to call Python functions from C++ ([pybind11 doc](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html)), but what is the intended way to call class methods? It feels like I should cast the `py::object` to a `My_Callback`, but I don't see how to do it.

The following lines seems to do the job, but is this really the intended way to do it?

```
void callPy(py::object f) {
    py::object mycallback = f.attr("do_something");
    mycallback("test");
}
```

Comment: The `py::detail::str_attr_accessor` that the `attr` method returns derives from `object_api`, so you can invoke `operator ()` on it directly: `f.attr("do_something")("test")`. Don't really see anything wrong with that, it's pretty much what happens in Python side -- you get the attribute corresponding to the member function, and then call it (and not worry about the underlying types or implementation).

Answer (score 1):

You can call a bound function on a python class passed in using the attr method to get the function object and then invoke it in a manner similar to std::function.

```
py::detail::str_attr_accessor do_something_func = my_callback.attr("do_something");
do_something_func("test");
```

In the latest master branch of pybind11 they have added extra typing objects you can cast the str_attr_accessor to if you want to be more explicit on what type you expect.

```
auto do_something_func = my_callback.attr("do_something").cast<py::typing::Callable<void(std::string)>>();
do_something_func("test");
```

If you want to have the function only accept objects of type My_Callback and have the generated type traits be correct you will have to create a custom implementation of py::object that checks for My_Callback  instances. This method also allows you to add a custom c++ method for handling do_something attr cast and invocation.

```
PYBIND11_NAMESPACE_BEGIN(PYBIND11_NAMESPACE)
  // create custom type object for more explicit type hints generated (My_Callback instead of Any)
  struct My_Callback : py::object
  {
     using py::object::object;

     static bool check_(handle h)
     {
        // this is probably not the best way to handle this, but I wanted to avoid string comparison
        // static so we only invoke once
        static py::type my_callback_type = py::module_::import("__main__").attr("My_Callback").cast<py::type>();
        return isinstance(h, my_callback_type);
     }

     void do_something(std::string&& something)
     {
        attr("do_something")(something);
     }
        
  };
PYBIND11_NAMESPACE_END(PYBIND11_NAMESPACE)

void callPy(py::My_Callback& my_callback)
{
   my_callback.do_something("test");
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind11_example, m)
{
   m.def("call_py", &callPy, "my_callback"_a);
}
```

This also generates a better help doc on the function

> Help on module pybind11_example:
>
> NAME
> pybind11_example
>
> FUNCTIONS
> call_py(...) method of builtins.PyCapsule instance
> call_py(my_callback: My_Callback) -> None

pybind11_stubgen will generate this as well

```
from __future__ import annotations
__all__ = ['call_py']
def call_py(my_callback: My_Callback) -> None:
    ...
```